# Replace a column in file with a column from a different file maintaing the format

Tags: bash, awk

I have two .dat files, f1.dat and f2.dat are attached in the below links. I am trying to copy the column from f2.dat file to f1.dat file while retaining the format of f1.dat using shell script command.

**File 1 (f1.dat)**

```
# Off---=0.210
# Angle=-2.3
# Br    L1--    L2--    L3---
6     0.047   0.093   44.660
7     0.062   0.101   43.290
8     0.097   0.108   36.730
9     0.142   0.105   28.290
10    0.187   0.097   21.590
11    0.209   0.092   19.070
12    0.232   0.088   17.010
13    0.276   0.081   13.850
14    0.320   0.077   11.340
15    0.363   0.074   9.8600
16    0.385   0.073   9.2800
17    0.396   0.072   8.9800
18    0.407   0.071   8.6900
19    0.421   0.070   8.3000
20    0.428   0.070   8.1000
21    0.435   0.070   7.9100
```

**File 2 (f2.dat)**

```
67.660
56.290
44.730
34.290
28.590
24.070
21.010
16.850
10.340
6.8600
5.2800
4.9800
4.6900
3.3000
2.1000
1.9100
```

I have tried the following command but all I got is a mess

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$0;next} {sub($4, a[FNR])}1' f1.dat f2.dat > final.dat
```

I want to replace the forth column in f1.dat with the column in file f2.dat. The output of f1.dat must look like;

---

```
# Off---=0000           
# Angle=0000            
# Br    L1--    L2--    L3---
6   0.047   0.093   67.660
7   0.062   0.101   56.290
8   0.097   0.108   44.730
9   0.142   0.105   34.290
10  0.187   0.097   28.590
11  0.209   0.092   24.070
12  0.232   0.088   21.010
13  0.276   0.081   16.850
14  0.320   0.077   10.340
15  0.363   0.074   6.8600
16  0.385   0.073   5.2800
17  0.396   0.072   4.9800
18  0.407   0.071   4.6900
19  0.421   0.070   3.3000
20  0.428   0.070   2.1000
21  0.435   0.070   1.9100
```

I would be greatly thankful for any help.

Comment: Put snippets of input file in your question. Don't expect people to click on some link to `mediafire.com`

Comment: also add an example of how a resulting line should look like.

Comment: Don't post links to short text files -- post the text files themselves. Few will enable javascript of spurious download sites to view your data. (**note:** your `f2.dat` does not contain a POSIX end-of-file)

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience! I have edited the post. look forward to hearing from you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$1;next} 
       FNR>3   {sub($NF"$",a[FNR-3])}1' file2 file1

# Off---=0.210
# Angle=-2.3
# Br    L1--    L2--    L3---
6     0.047   0.093   67.660
7     0.062   0.101   56.290
8     0.097   0.108   44.730
9     0.142   0.105   34.290
10    0.187   0.097   28.590
11    0.209   0.092   24.070
12    0.232   0.088   21.010
13    0.276   0.081   16.850
14    0.320   0.077   10.340
15    0.363   0.074   6.8600
16    0.385   0.073   5.2800
17    0.396   0.072   4.9800
18    0.407   0.071   4.6900
19    0.421   0.070   3.3000
20    0.428   0.070   2.1000
21    0.435   0.070   1.9100
```

Note that your posted expected output is not maintaining the format.

Comment: Your suggested code is not giving the right output! Thanks anyway!

Comment: did you try with the input files you posted here?  What did you get?

Comment: I have got only one column!

Comment: pay attention to the order for files: file2 first then file1.

Comment: My bad! Sorry again. It works perfect after switching the order! Thank you very much!

Comment: NP, if you think this answers your question please mark it accordingly...

Comment: What if I wanted to replace the third column instead "L2---"?

Comment: Here it's anchored with the end of line, guaranteeing the last column match.  Same approach won't work since there may be false matches if the same value is in column 1.  If you let go formatting, you can just use `$3=a[FNR-3]` instead of `sub` function.  Or, add back formatting with `printf`,  May warrant a new question!

Comment: Do you want me to post new question for that?

Comment: If my suggestions are not enough, better post a new question so that other people can chip in.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following one-liner you can replace the `4th` column of `f1.dat` file with the content of `f2.dat`:

```
awk '{ if (NR > 3) { getline f2 < "f2.dat"; printf "%-5d %8.3f %8.3f %8.4f\n",$1,$2,$3,f2 } else print $0 }' f1.dat
```

Using `getline` you can read input from `f2.dat` file into `f2` variable. Then print the fields from f1.dat and f2.dat in the desired order, formatted with `printf`.

If you would like to replace different columns, you can change the order of `$1,$2,$3,f2` and eventually add `$4` depending on your needs. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48331416/replace-any-column-in-file-with-a-column-from-a-different-file-maintaing-the-for/#48331889).